# how can I use underscore template (<%%>) way I use it in PHP (<?php ?>)

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

How can I fix this?

```
<%= if(comments.length) { %>
  <%=_.each(comments, function (comment) {%>
    <div><%=comment.message%></div>
  <%=});%>
<%=}%>
```

where I can do it in PHP like:

```php
<?php if(count($comments) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($comments as $comment){ ?>
     <div><?=$comment->message?></div>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is. That seems like a reasonable underscore template…

Comment: Don't use `<% %>`, their support will be removed from PHP6.

Comment: @Adnan The first example isn't PHP, it's an underscore template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% if(comments.length) {
  _.each(comments, function (comment) { %>
    <div><%=comment.message%></div>
  <% });
} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you are looking for...
remove the evaluating `=`s from the `<%=`s

```
<% if(comments.length) { %>
  <% _.each(comments, function (comment) {%>
    <div><%=comment.message%></div>
  <% }); %>
<% } %>
```